# Multithreading InvalidOperationException C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates, richtextbox

i have a button.when i click this button i make a new thread
then goes to ThreadProcSafe method and i want over there to
set the the response into the richtextbox.but when i try to do
that i always take an InvalidOperationException and says to me cross
thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than
the thread it was created on.any suggestions?

```
 delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);


    private Thread demoThread = null;

   private void Go_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        this.demoThread =new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadProcSafe));

        this.demoThread.Start();
    }





    // This method send a request get response

    private void ThreadProcSafe()
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        this.SetText(richTextBox1.Text);
    }


   private void SetText(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.richTextBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are doing this `richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();` inside your `ThreadProcSafe`. What you probably wanted to do is this:

```
private void ThreadProcSafe()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string res = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    this.SetText(res);
}
```

Note that you should wrap your streams into `using` statements so that they get disposed properly.